# Python: read binary file into an array

Tags: python, binary, decode

I was trying to import binary data and process it on python:

```
with open("myData", "rb") as binary_file:

    data = binary_file.read()
    print(data)
```

> > b'\x00\x00\x00\t0.000000\r\x00\x00\x00\t0.173902\r\x00\x00\x00\t0.343819\r\x00\x00\x00\t0.491724\r\x00\x00\x00\t0.660698\r\x00\x00\x00\t0.791551\r\x00\x00\x00\t0.890531\r\x00\x00\x00\t0.987460\r\x00\x00\x00\t1.083403\r\x00\x00\x00\t1.180349\r\x00\x00\x00\t1.274278\r\x00\x00\x00\t1.372280\r\x00\x00\x00\t1.470185\r\x00\x00\x00\t1.570129\r\x00\x00\x00\t1.668071\r\x00\x00\x00\t1.764061\r\x00\x00\x00\t1.861004\r\x00\x00\x00\t1.956906\r\x00\x00\x00\t2.051896\r\x00\x00\x00\t2.150841\r\x00\x00\x00\t2.249743\r\x00\x00\x00\t2.345730\r\x00\x00\x00\t2.443689\r\x00\x00\x00\t2.537581\r\x00\x00\x00\t2.636510\r\x00\x00\x00\t2.738474\r\x00\x00\x00\t2.843399\r\x00\x00\x00\t2.941346\r\x00\x00\x00\t3.041276\r\x00\x00\x00\t3.138279\r\

The above just a portion of my whole data. I was trying to convert to string and it doesn't work...

```
with open("D:/Python/reshape 3D/measurement data/112719_binary/time", "rb") as binary_file:

    data = binary_file.read(32)
    data = data.decode('utf-8')
    print(data)
```

How should I convert back and put them in a list?
The results above should be [0.000000, 0.173902, 0.343819.....]

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: must use 'rb'? 'r' and encoding='u8' is woring?

Comment: I would suggest you give a little more info on why you want to turn it into a string, and what you're trying to achieve in order to get better solutions. cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have a bytes image of a two-column, tab-separated table, where the first column is all zeros and the last one has other field, starting from the second, and convert them to floats:

```
list(map(float, data.split()[1::2]))
#[0.173902, 0.491724, 0.791551, 0.98746, 1.180349,...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I need list(map(float, data.split()[1::2])), though.